# Is it ok to set CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION twice?

Tags: curl, callback, libcurl

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, Disable_Verbose);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, Save_Page);
```

This is just a little part of my code, I invoked CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION twice here and I don't know if it's ok to do that.

EDIT: Thanks to Benjamin Lindley, this worked for me:

```
size_t Write_Callback_Func(void *server_data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *user_data)
{
    ((string*)user_data)->append((char*)server_data, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

Comment: You don't *invoke* the option there, you *set* it.

Comment: @DanielStenberg yes yes you’re right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Ok' in what sense? It's okay in that it won't cause a runtime error. But there's not any reason you would do it (*not without a call to `curl_easy_perform` in between*). The second call replaces the first. It is similar to doing this:

```
int x;
x = 2;  // useless
x = 3;
```

If you are expecting it to call both of your write functions when you call `curl_easy_perform`, it won't. Only the most recently set function will be called. You will need to write a separate write function which calls them both, if that's what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, I put those two together in a single function and it worked for me, thanks again for the help!